# Impacts of daily work with gateway-based parental control

Tags: gateway, parental-controls

I am considering to install a gateway-based parental control system at home.

I specifically want to activate ratings-based web filtering.

From the documentation of commercial solutions such as [ZyWall USG 20](http://www.zyxel.com/us/en/products_services/zywall_usg_200_100_plus_100_50_20w_20.shtml?t=p), I understand that the internet users will be attributed a `username` and `password` to access the internet.

What bothers me is the impact of this authentication. I was not able to understand when (how frequently and at which stage of the access attempt) the users will have to authenticate.

I am afraid it would be too complex for a 7-8 year old kid, and then reduce its autonomy in accessing internet.

Can anyone help me with a description of the typical authentication use case ?

Comment: Why not ask Zyxel?

Comment: Well I might try but they would give me a commercial, "all-positive" answer. I ask you because I think users are the best to share expercience. Also, product reviews do not focus on these aspects.

Comment: Your question is very straightforward: "When (how frequently and at which stage of the access attempt) will the users have to authenticate." If they can't answer that they don't want to put effort in selling (hint).

Comment: @JanDoggen it makes sense. I followed your advice. I'll post their answer here. Remains the point that existing users might have more accurate expericence than salesguys - and it might be different for another brand.

Comment: @JanDoggen : The answer from Zyxel is so poor I can't post it as an answer ! Extensive quote : "When a logout is done, or after a timeout period".".  They don't tell how ; and they don't tell the how long the timeout is.